# php regular expression for unicode

Tags: php, regex

I have some text where unicode is written as text like this

```
There areu25ba 2 boys.
```

it should be like this

```
There are&#x25ba 2 boys.
```

Replace 'u' with '&#x' if there is unicode character.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yep. I just need to show characters in html page than unicode text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive way would be:

```
preg_replace('/u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/','&#x$1;',$string);
```

But I doubt 'udaff' would appreciate it.

Comment: Wrikken, I've tried to run this code. but its not printing character.
echo(preg_replace('/u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/', "&#x$1", "u25ba works?"));

Comment: Shahid: you missed an update to the regex itself too (which Gumbo pointed out), now fixed in answer.